# Does the order of arguments in a conditional statement affect execution time in php?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

As far as I know when writing a conditional statement in C such as the following:

> if ( some_function() == 100 && my_var
>   == 5 ) { //do something }

is slower to execute than

> if ( my_var == 5 && some_function() ==
>   100 ) { //do something }

because it's faster to execute the my_var == 5 rather than all of the code in the function ( because if my_var != 5, then the rest of the if statement would not even be executed )...so I am wondering if the same is true for conditional statements in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is true for PHP as well, because PHP, like C, [makes use of](http://www.kekh.com/chapter-6/short-circuit-evaluation/) [short-circuit conditional evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).